# SQLITE strange timestamp and IOS

Tags: ios, sqlite, unix, nsdate

I'm trying to display a simple tableview in IOS with data from Sqlite. My database date is stored as a timestamp. I thought was an unix timestamps but if i try to use `dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970` i've really strange result.

Examples of date rows stored:

```
1352208510267
1352208512266
1352208514266
1352208516266
1352208530266
1352208532265
```

Comment: If you delete last three numbers, it is a date around nov 2012.

Comment: oh well, you gave us some numbers. How are we supposed to guess how you evaluate those? I am sorry to tell you, that I cant crunch those down into real dates with my head alone... but I can tell you that SQLite actually is not storing dates as DATE datatype, but uses its date functions to display them ( http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html see pt 1.2 ). And because of this, you would need to show us your inserting/reading code to sqlite

Answer (score 2):

Use a query like this

```
SELECT datetime(timestamp, 'unixepoch') from YOURTABLENAME
WHERE id = someId;
```

This should convert it to some readable value.

Have a look [here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

Comment: Sorry guys. My Sql Lite Studio was displaying an old database connection (journal cause). Deleted the connection and recreate now the stored number (1365511532/1000) is the current date I'm looking for. Sorry again.

Comment: Even so, this is still a good way to get human readable dates out of SQLlite.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer [here](http://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2013/04/14/timestamp-column-in-ios-sqlite-database/).  I compared the results with the previous answers:

```
SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', datetime(ZDATE+978307200, 'unixepoch', 'localtime')), datetime(ZDATE, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') FROM ZTABLE
```

The query with the adjustment for Apple's epoch (Jan 1 2001) gives me the correct date:

```
"2015-09-29 20:50:51", "1984-09-28 20:50:51"
"2015-09-29 21:03:10", "1984-09-28 21:03:10"
"2015-09-29 21:25:30", "1984-09-28 21:25:30"
```

Answer (score 0):

Unix timestamps are defined as the number of *seconds* since Jan 1 1970.
Just now, this would be about 1365525702.

Your values are one thousand times larger, i.e., they are measured in *milliseconds*.

Decide whether you actually need the millisecond precision, and then add `* 1000` or `/ 1000` at the appropriate places.

Comment: IOS also uses a different epoch than Unix - 2001-01-01 00:00:00, so the numbers are 41 years off.